# What is the explicit equation that converts Cartesian coordinates to elliptical coordinates?

Tags: coordinate-systems

All of the solutions that I have seen so far require solving an implicit equation after substituting in whatever $x$, $y$, and $z$ are. What are the explicit equations for each elliptical coordinate in a two dimensions and three dimensions

Comment: Elliptic coordinates. I am using it for Euler's three-body problem.

Comment: looks like [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_coordinate_system).

Answer (score 2):

You haven't told us which convention you're using, but the one that I'm most used to is
$$
\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{z-u_i}{z-\lambda_i} = 1 + \sum_{m=1}^n \frac{x_m^2}{z-\lambda_m}
,
$$
where $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ are Cartesian coordinates and $(u_1,\dots,u_n)$ are ellipsoidal coordinates (with parameters $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n$).

The way to read this is that the coordinates $u_i$ are the zeros of the $n$th degree polynomial in $z$ that you get in the numerator when putting the right-hand side on a common denominator.

For $n=2$, this means that $z=u_1$ and $z=u_2$ are the roots of the quadratic equation
$$
(z-\lambda_1)(z-\lambda_2) + x_1^2 (z-\lambda_2) + x_2^2 (z-\lambda_1) = 0
,
$$
(and you can of course write them explicitly with the usual formula
$u_{1,2} = \ldots \pm \sqrt{\ldots}$),
but for $n=3$ you would have to solve a cubic equation, so the expressions for $u_{1,2,3}$ are a complete mess; trying to write them down is not worth the trouble.

The expressions going the other way (expressing $x_m^2$ in terms of the $u_i$) are nice, though.